# Python, use the lists in the list, or objects in the list?

Tags: python, list, object, performance

I have a list and in each list element, I need some details. 
What will be more efficient to use the list in the list 
[['brown', 'wood', 2], ['red', 'box', 3 ],...]
Or create a new class for the parameters(details) of color, type, etc.. and creating objects from this class in every element of the list. 
[object1,object2,...]

Or any other solution?

Comment: You have to define what you mean by efficient. Do you mean execution speed, memory usage, human programing/debugging time?

Comment: mostly, execution speed but the ease of understanding for others, and memory usage is also important because they do not yet know how big this list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of lists will be more efficient(as in less overhead for function calls, object creation, object destruction etc and take up less space in memory), however creating a new class might be better for readability, writability, and maintainability.

My opinion is that you shouldn't worry about these micro optimizations unless you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Lists-in-lists are typically more efficient (builtin types), but you shouldn't care about efficiency until you have to; it will be more maintainable and easier to work with if you use objects. There's the old adage:

> "Never optimize until you need to."